# Remove non numeric characters and spaces in google sheet cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to remove non-numeric character in a cell. Can someone help what should be the right formula?
Assuming `A1` has a value of `(453) 567-1234`.
What should be the formula for the cell to have only `4535671234`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many regex patterns to return just digits.

The following is one of them

Returned as number:

```
=REGEXREPLACE($A$1,"\D+", "")+0
```

Returned as text/string:

```
=REGEXREPLACE($A$1,"\D+", "")
```

[image: REGEX to return just digits]

Functions used / more info:

- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [`RE2 regular expression syntax reference`](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have only the digits, you can have the following:

- result as a string: `=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"[^\d]", "")`
- result as a number: `=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"[^\d]", ""))`

[image]

For more references of the regex language google sheets uses, you have the [documentation here](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt).