# How to simplify this google sheets regex sequence?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I want to make the following transformation to a set of datas in my google spreadsheets :

- 6 views ->   6
- 73K views -> 73000
- 3650 -> 3650
- 163K views -> 163000
- 1.2K views -> 1200
- 52.5K -> 52500

All the datas are in a column and depending on the case I need to apply a specific transformation.
I tried to put all the regex in one formula but I failed. I always had a case over two regular expressions etc.

Anyaway I end up making these regex one case by one case in different columns. It works fine but I feel like it could slowdown the sheet since I except a lot of data coming into this sheet.

Here is the sheet : [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A-wM6xTSyDdK-hI58FBVnWR8hDqDaWsfrps0YZADaok/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Possibly answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64171603/remove-non-numeric-characters-and-spaces-in-google-sheet-cell

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _manually entered_ desired results there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regexreplace()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 1 / 
    value( 
      regexreplace( 
        regexreplace(trim(A2:A), "\s*K", "e3"), 
        " views", "" 
      ) 
    ) 
  ^ -1 ) 
)
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A-wM6xTSyDdK-hI58FBVnWR8hDqDaWsfrps0YZADaok/edit#gid=1286880488).

Comment: Thank you for your response but I can not make it works on my real working sheet. It throws me an #ERROR : Formula parse error.
Do I need to toggle some parameters to use the ARRAYFORMULA() function (never used it before) ?

Comment: @CodeTinkerer: Assuming there is no real error in the formula, it is most likely due to you not removing the line changes. `arrayformula()` is always supported.

Comment: In the event your spreadsheet locale uses commas `,` as decimal separators, you will have to use semicolons `;` as formula argument separators. In other words, replace all the commas in the formula with semicolons. Line breaks work fine in Google Sheets formulas and do not need to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

replace 'views' using regex: `/(?<=(\d*\.?\d+\K?)) views/gi`
To replace 'K' with or without decimal value, first, detect K then replace K with an empty string and multiply by 1000.

use call back function as:

```
txt.replace(/(?<=(\d*\.?\d+\K?)) views/gi, '').replace(/(?<=\d)\.?\d+K/g, x => x.replace(/K/gi, '')*1000)
```

code:

```
arr = [`6 views`,
`73K views`,
`3650`,
`163K views`,
`1.2K views`,
`52.5K`];


arr.forEach(txt => {
  console.log(txt.replace(/(?<=(\d*\.?\d+\K?)) views/gi, '').replace(/(?<=\d)\.?\d+K/g, x => x.replace(/K/gi, '')*1000))
})
```

Output:

```
6
73000
3650
163000
1200
52500
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :-) 
I upvoted your response but it does not display since I do not have enough reputation !

Comment: No issue. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

Say your inputs are in column A. Empty cells allowed. In any other column,

```
=arrayformula(if(A2:A<>"",value(substitute(substitute(A2:A," views",""),"K","e3")),))
```

works.

Adjust the range `A2:A` as needed.

Also note that non-empty cells with empty strings are ignored.

---

Basically, since Google Sheet's regex engine doesn't support look around, it is more efficient to take advantage of the rather strict patterns in your application and use [`substitute()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I will also try this solution :-)